# Enforce unique constraint on 1 of n values

Tags: postgresql, constraint

Let's say I have a table like this.

```
create table foo (
    id serial primary key,
    kind smallint not null check (kind >= 0 and kind < 3)
);
```

With that check constraint, Postgres will only allow `kind` to be an int between 0 and 2, inclusive. So something like this is valid.

```
id | kind
---------
1  | 0
2  | 0
3  | 1
4  | 1
5  | 2
6  | 2
```

However is there a way to say, "at most 1 row can have the value 2"?

```
time=1
id | kind
---------
1  | 0
2  | 0
3  | 1
4  | 1
5  | 2

time=2
id | kind
---------
1  | 0
2  | 2
3  | 1
4  | 0
5  | 0

time=3
id | kind
---------
1  | 0
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 0
5  | 0
```

Different rows should be allowed to have `kind=2` at different points in time, but at most 1 row can have `kind=2`.

Note, the other values should be unrestricted. You can have as many `kind=0`s and `kind=1`s as you like.

Comment: Your example is invalid.  Is the column named "kind", or "status"?

Comment: Bah. Sorry, typo. Took that from a different file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create unique partial index:

```
create unique index on foo (kind) where kind=2;
```